# Importing Int into SQL Server 2008 R2 from Text File

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, type-conversion

I was trying to use the import wizard of SQL Server 2008 to import data I have exported from another SQL Server database saved to a text file.  The wizard tried to import the data as varchar, and when I went to change the data type to int I couldn't find an int data type.  There were a couple of int options (4/8 bit (un)signed int).  Which is the SQL int type?

Thanks

Comment: Depends how big/small your integers are.  What's the largest and smallest integer size you have in the file, would you guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "standard" SQL Server `int` is `4 bytes, signed`. See [here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).

So, in T-SQL, if you do something like:

```
declare @i int
```

then `@i` will be a signed, four-byte integer with possible ranges of -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647).

Answer (score 0):

if you can export the information on the source once again I would advice you [ssms](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) what can export you a dump with insert statements...

if not try a connection over ms excel ... this works quite good... (create table first and then copy paste by exceling around)

Comment: The table had a million rows in it.  Excel couldn't handle it.  Thanks for the idea though.